# This doesn't seem right? Javascript isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm creating my Javascript and have had help. I'm making the following fields required..

First Name
Last Name
Phone
Email

Comment: your question should specify exactly what you are trying to understand.

Comment: @adrichman On submit or when you fix the error next to the field it doesn't dissapear the javascript that is, also its' not executing my phone field maximum 10 minnimum 8.

Comment: Do you mean your validation persists although the inputs are valid?

Comment: As for the email validation, it does disappear when I try to retype a valid one. As for the phone, yeah, your validation seems wrong

Comment: @Newbie Yeah I don't understand why it's not dissapearing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to limit your phone character:

```
['phone', elem('phone').value.length > 7 && elem('phone').value.length < 11 && /^(\+\d{1,2})?[\d ()-]+$/.test(elem('phone').value)]
```

As for your email validation, I don't see something went wrong with that. The error message does disappear after a while.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy, but the errors don't dissapear when you write something in the field? First Name or anything wont' dissapear for me?

Comment: What do you mean by First Name? Your first name already restrict numeric character so where comes the error? So which part has the error actually?

Comment: Look at my JSFIDDLE, click submit without inputting anything there's an error(s) next to each field. Those error's don't go away at all.

Comment: You should do something like textbox onChange, then perform the validation. The way you did from what I see is when your form onSubmit, then you perform the validations.

Comment: You reckon you could give me an example on 1? In JSFIDDLE? Cheers